# php artisan migrate не выполняет миграцию laravel

Tags: php, laravel, миграция, artisan

Использую OpenServer HTTP: Apache-PHP-7-Nginx-1.19 PHP: PHP-7-x64 MySQL-5.5
При выполнении `php artisan migrate` выдает ошибку:

```
In Connection.php line 664:  
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = psypoint and table_name =
migrations)  
In Connector.php line 67:  
could not find driver
```

Подскажите как решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была проблема в версии MySQL. Поставив х64 все пошло как по маслу.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что отключен PDO

ПКМ на иконке OpenServer - Дополнительно - Конфигурация - PHP7х64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле конфигурации уберите `;` перед строкой `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` и перезагрузите сервер.

Как вариант еще можно попробовать выбрать другую версию PHP - 7.0 (x32) или 7.1/7.2.

Чтобы проверить работает ли PDO вообще, сделайте вывод phpinfo и поищите в нем этот блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Убрана она. У меня получилось исправить ошибку, не знаю как, я просто менял разные версии php и Mysql и перезагружал сервер, после вернул к исходным и все запустилось. Я не знаю что повлияло на исправление((

Comment: Ну мой ответ - как наиболее частая проблема, ну а глюки - их никто не отменял :)